# Breaking recursion from listeners

Tags: java, recursion, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I'm trying to break a special case that makes this code recursive.

I have a Javafx game where there are human and computer players each play when it's his turn and there can be many rounds.

A computer is supposed to play automatically and move to the next player immediately and show no direct indication to the UI (but it's possible to review what it did afterwards).

The problem is in the case where there are only computer players, we will come here the moment the `currentBoardPane` was loaded, enter the condition since all players are computers, set the board of the next player, and then without finishing the call, call this same function again:

```
    currentBoardPane.addListener((e) -> {  
        if(gameManager.checkIfCurrentPlayerIsComputer()){

            gameManager.playAutoMovesForCurrentPlayer();
            gameManager.setNextPlayer(); // it does current player property = next player

            //update board on scene
            currentBoardPaneIndex = ((currentBoardPaneIndex + 1) % gameManager.getPlayers().size());
            currentBoardPane.setValue(boardPanes.get((currentBoardPaneIndex))); //this is a recursive call
        }
    });
```

Instead of this, if I subscribe a listener to the `currentPlayer` property in `GameManager` then I still need to call `setNextPlayer()` from that listener which is again recursive.

I can make a special case if all players are a computer, then run the game from a `while(true){}` instead of listeners and binds but there has to be a better way to break this recursion.

Is there a way to not get into recursion while still having listeners and binds?

Notes:

`currentBoardPane` signifies the current game board on the screen and it's an `ObjectProperty`.

Comment: If the `playAutoMovesForCurrentPlayer()` method took a long time (e.g. you  were playing chess, or some other game where the computation for the move was extensive), then you would wrap the call to `playAutoMovesForCurrentPlayer()` in a `Task`, execute it on a background thread, and perform the remaining code (`setNextPlayer()`, update index and pane) in the `onSucceeded` handler. That would break the recursion, since your handler wouldn't directly invoke the change. That might not be a desirable solution if you know the moves are close to instantaneous, but it would solve the problem.

Comment: It's a simple game and the "AI" is just picking in random so it's instant.

Comment: Yes, but it still solves the problem. If I understand correctly, each move updates the UI, right? So if you used the solution you propose (`while (true) { doMoves(); }`) you would have to put that in a background thread and use `Platform.runLater(...)` to update the UI, else you would not see the UI change (until the loop completes, which looks like it would never happen). So it seems either way you need to work with a background thread.

Comment: The while loop will invoke methods that update the UI with events or listeners, but it will still block the javafx main thread until it finishes? Then I'll probably prefer to use your first advice.

Comment: If it's running on the FX Application Thread, then yes, it will block that thread until it finishes. (If it's not, you are already creating a background thread anyway, so either way you are working with threads.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the following assumptions about your code:

1. Everything is currently running on the FX Application Thread
2. The `currentBoardPane.setValue(...)` causes the UI to update (so you update the UI each move)

then a "quick and dirty" way to do this is:

```
currentBoardPane.addListener((e) -> {  
    if(gameManager.checkIfCurrentPlayerIsComputer()){

        gameManager.playAutoMovesForCurrentPlayer();

        //update board on scene
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            gameManager.setNextPlayer(); // it does current player property = next player
            currentBoardPaneIndex = ((currentBoardPaneIndex + 1) % gameManager.getPlayers().size());
            currentBoardPane.setValue(boardPanes.get((currentBoardPaneIndex))); //this is a recursive call
        });
    }
});
```

This delegates the updates to a new `Runnable`, schedules that runnable to execute on the FX Application Thread, and exits the handler immediately. Thus the call to `currentBoardPane.setValue(...)` is executed later and is no longer recursive.

In fact, if you do just a little more work:

```
private final Executor aiExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// ...

currentBoardPane.addListener((e) -> {  
    if(gameManager.checkIfCurrentPlayerIsComputer()){

        Task<Void> makeMoveTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                gameManager.playAutoMovesForCurrentPlayer();
                return null ;
            }
        };

        makeMoveTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {

            //update board on scene
            gameManager.setNextPlayer(); // it does current player property = next player
            currentBoardPaneIndex = ((currentBoardPaneIndex + 1) % gameManager.getPlayers().size());
            currentBoardPane.setValue(boardPanes.get((currentBoardPaneIndex))); //this is a recursive call
        });

        aiExecutor.execute(makeMoveTask);
    }
});
```

then this is exactly the code you would use if computing the move took enough time that it would not be acceptable to block the UI while it was happening. (And if computing the move takes very little time, this will still work just fine.) This assumes that `playAutoMovesForCurrentPlayer()` doesn't update the UI.

Comment: Well `playAutoMovesForCurrentPlayer()` does have events or listeners in the controller that update the UI...

Comment: So you can just use the first option. Probably though it is cleaner to separate out the logic that computes the move, however trivial that is, from the logic that takes a representation of a move and updates the UI with it.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.