# RunLater on current thread or give a task to current thread to run later

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, java-8

I want to achieve what `Platform.runLater()` does but on the current thread and the program isn't related to JavaFX, it's a Tomcat server.

I tried to do `Platform.runLater(this::foo);` but I'm pretty sure it doesn't do anything. Probably because there's no JavaFX thread to do it.

I'd rather not open a `ScheduledExecutorService` because it's going to be another thread on many instances (so many threads), not to mention the method it would need to run is `synchronized` so I smell a deadlock.

I couldn't find any useful methods on `Thread.currentThread()` (`run` and `start` don't take parameters).

Is there another option to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the code that would be "run later"? Because this semantic ist not really one that is (directly) present in the Request/Response oriented Servlet API.

Comment: It's code that needs to run independently from the client, in short, it's a game and this code runs the "AI" player. It's like the problem I had on JavaFX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395942/breaking-recursion-from-listeners @JohannesWachter

Comment: You can’t schedule a task for an arbitrary existing thread. This only works for frameworks whose threads actively check some queue of tasks to execute. But this seems to be an xy problem, your desire to use the current thread stems from trying to solve a problem, you can’t solve this way.

Comment: It's not even possible to schedule a task to happen after some time on the current thread like on javascript? @Holger

Comment: @kuhaku: In JavaScript, you are only scheduling actions for the event handling queue, much like `Platform.runLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. The fact that the whole environment is cloned for web workers, if you think of that, is a sign of a *limitation* rather than a feature. In an environment, where threads can execute arbitrary code, you can’t expect that arbitrary code magically stop whatever it is doing and starting to execute your scheduled action.

Comment: So the only way to achieve this is to run it from another thread like `ScheduledExecutorService` or spawn a new thread just for this method? @Holger

Comment: It’s not clear what you want to achieve or why it is so relevant to you, which thread will execute your scheduled action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a [newSingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) to achieve this, since it can take multiple runnables to a queue and run them sequentially, it can be given tasks from several places and it will run them one by one, it's similar to `platform.runLater`.

Having a single thread that all instances of the class hold a reference to, solves the "many threads" problem.

It also won't cause a deadlock because it will at most wait for just one other thread to finish the synchronized function and then run just this one function.